# Cropped FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, material-design

I can’t make the correct button. If we set android: `layout_height = "90dp"` for CoordinatorLayout, then everything turns out, but I would like it without hard values. Can I do this?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            app:tint="@null" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
            app:menu="@menu/days_bottomappbar_menu" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In app/build.gradle, you import:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

And in xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_24px"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I also had to use android: layout_weight= "1", and also adjust the weight of other components.